# Insert Word cross-reference to a comment

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007, cross-reference

In Word 2007, I would like to insert a cross-reference in one comment to another comment.

While in the comment, I can go to `Insert --> Cross-Reference`, but I do not find any "comment" section in the Cross-Reference dialog box, nor do comments appear in the "numbered items" section.  Note that this applies to inserting a reference in the document body as well.

How does one insert a cross-reference to a comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot : A comment is not a legal Reference type.

Answer (score 5):

I've found a work-around: I can insert a bookmark in the comment and then insert a reference to the bookmark.

I don't get the label of the comment, but I can quote any portion of it.  Given harrymc's answer, I suspect that's the best I'll be able to do.